# Is it better to save/insert the hashed string in database table before saving the password?

Tags: python, django, hash, bcrypt

```
import bcrypt

hashedstring = bcrypt.gensalt()
password = bcrypt.hashpw(password,hashedstring)
```

Should I save the hashedstring everytime in the database table field to login succeesfully next time getting the hashed string?

Or should I use a static pre-generated hashed string in code?

Comment: It's more secure to generate a new salt for every password, and store them alongside passwords.

Comment: (as has been pointed out to me below, bcrypt includes the salt in the output, so it needn't be stored separately)

Comment: Looking at your recent questions, and having some ideas about what you're trying to do I'd suggest you read Django docs, in particular about [Authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/). Thinking that you have no time to read the docs and that they are complicated, you're trying to make things that are already done, and getting into much more complication. If you'd use build-in Django features you'd already implement what you want in very simple and clear way. Now you need to deal with bcrypt, salt generation and what else in the future.

Comment: @demalexx Reading those docs, I see the options are MD5, SHA1 and Crypt - BCrypt has significant advantages over all of those, so depending on the application, it may be a better idea to use it, but I agree that in most cases, reinventing the wheel is pointless.

Comment: @Lattyware BCrypt support is to included in the upcoming 1.4 Django release, and automated algorithm upgrading is included too (which is interesting in the case of BCrypt, as you will want to upgrade the work factor from time to time) so guru might want to use SHA-1 until 1.4 is released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The salt you use to hash the password is stored in the resulting hash - this means there is no need to store it in the database, as it can be recovered from the hash.

According to the project page, this can be done like so:

```
# Store a hash.
import bcrypt
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())
store_in_db(user, hashed) #Where user is the user to load the hash for, and store_in_db does what it says on the tin.

# Check against an existing hash
import bcrypt
hashed = load_from_db(user) # (get the password of the user from database) Where user is the user to load the hash for, and load_from_db does what it says on the tin.
if bcrypt.hashpw(password, hashed) == hashed: # Where password is a plaintext password attempt.
        print "It matches"
else:
        print "It does not match"
```

And yes, you should use a different salt for each value - which BCrypt's design encourages.

Comment: The whole point of hashes is that you can't recover what went into them.

Comment: The hash string bcrypt outputs is xxxxyyyyyyyy (not accurate length), where xs are the salt, not hashed, and ys are the hash of the password and salt. Hence to get the salt, you just get the first n characters.

Comment: @ThomasK: The point is that you cannot recover the **password**. The salt is not that secret. It just ensures that even the two identical passwords result in different hashes.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I haven't come across bcrypt before.

Comment: No worries - it's something that most of the implementations don't make very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Use a new salt for each password. (EDIT: with bcrypt you needn't store the salt separately)

Imagine if an attacker gets the password database from a website. If all the passwords are hashed using a common salt, then the attacker can easily find people using common passwords:

```
hashedpwd = somehash('swordfish' + salt)
```

Then just a database query is needed to find everyone using 'swordfish' as a password. There will always be a substantial fraction of users with quite common passwords.

On the other hand, if every password has its own salt, and there are 1 million passwords in the database, an attacker must calculate 1 million hashes in order to check just one password, so it's much more secure.

Comment: As I point out in my answer, in the specific case of BCrypt, the salt is stored in the output from the hash function, and storing it separately in your database would be redundant.